# Custom Behaviour for JSON Merge

Tags: scala, json4s

I am using using Json4s version 3.2.11 and Scala version 2.11.6

I need a different behaviour for dealing with two JArray fields when using the merge function (intersection rather then union) and am wondering if there is a nice way to achieve this?

The current behaviour is,

```
val lotto1 = parse("""{
   "lotto":{
       "lotto-id":5,
       "winning-numbers":[2,45,34,23,7,5,3]
      }
   }""")

val lotto2 = parse("""{
   "lotto":{
       "winning-numbers":[2,45,34]
      }
   }""")

val mergedLotto = lotto1 merge lotto2

pretty(render(mergedLotto))
{
  "lotto":{
    "lotto-id":5,
    "winning-numbers":[2,45,34,23,7,5,3]
  }
}
```

But my desired result is,

```
{
  "lotto":{
    "lotto-id":5,
    "winning-numbers":[2,45,34]
  }
}
```

From my investigation, I am hoping to bring my own MergeDep (https://github.com/json4s/json4s/blob/3.6/ast/src/main/scala/org/json4s/Merge.scala) into scope however access modifiers do not allow.